# I am not able to bring on Mysql in CDH 4.7 in Virtual box

Tags: mysql, hadoop

When I type MySQL in the command shell I should get MySQL prompt however it is not what I get rather the below error.

bash: MySQL: command not found

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Just downloaded the mysql patch for centos online and installed it.. Works like a charm now.